# Freeze Time test cases fail when a variable is used to reference the time

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest, freezegun

I'm using `freeze-time` to run my python `unittest` Test cases.

A dummy test case:

```py
@freeze_time('2020-01-01')
def test_something(self):
  expected_output = {'time': '2020-01-01'}

  output = call_tested_code()

  self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
```

Main code / Code that is being tested:

```py
GET_CURRENT_TIME = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def call_tested_code():
  return {'time': GET_CURRENT_TIME}
```

This is failing, as the output is giving current_date instead of frozen date.
It was working when the `GET_CURRENT_TIME` was a lambda, but that results in different timestamps for my code, which I don't want.

Feel free to comment if any additional Information is required. Thanks

Comment: What wrong output are you getting now?

Comment: The current time is using the actual current time, i,e. today's date and time, instead of the frozen value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tested code is being imported before your test function, so `GET_CURRENT_TIME` is evaluated before your `freeze_time` so that's the problem.

To solve if either import `call_tested_code` inside the test function or put it inside a lambda or another callable, as mentioned by you.

```
@freeze_time('2020-01-01')
def test_something(self):
    from package import call_tested_code # edit here with your correct import
    expected_output = {'time': '2020-01-01'}
    output = call_tested_code()
    self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
```

Also, I think you should change the expected output to be a datetime string not only date as your `GET_CURRENT_TIME` uses this format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.

Comment: Thanks, that string formatting is more of a technicality, but if I have multiple test cases, would I have to import within each function / class (unittest.TestCase)?

Comment: @piyushdaga You could make a [raw use](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun#raw-use) at the top of your test suite around your import, this way you should only do it once, but I haven't tested.

Comment: @piyushdaga Have this answered your question? If it did, don't forget to mark it as answer. Hope I helped ;D